How to make alt tab preview windows bigger?
I want to make the window previews of alt tab bigger. Is there a way to double the width and length of the windows in alt tab?
I found these registry edits, but its for Windows 10 (I'm using Windows 11):

You confirmed those keys don’t accomplish what you want?

Have you considered WIN-TAB? they are a different kind of Alt-Tab, that work in both Windows 10 and 11, but their tiles are much bigger. After you hit Win-Tab once, Now use arrow keys and enter to switch. You can also click with your mouse to switch. Win-Tab twice will exit out without making a switch.
